# Is it possible to set security user for a database with Entity Framework Core using code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to know if it is possible to set from a SeedMethod a database security user which belongs to my network? I would like to use code first for that, to make the configuration at once and not going as an database admin user and add all user groups I have on my network that should have access to my database.

[image]

Comment: EF is ORM(object-relation mapping) framework, database implementation details are not it's responsibility. You can always run plain sql queries with database provider.

Comment: @Fabio running pain sql was not the option I was looking for but certainly you can do it inside the SeedMethod.